# What is the difference between using crontab -e and /etc/crontab

Tags: debian, cron, root, reboot, etc

I wish to run stuff from startup and also trigger reboots using cron.

I was using `sudo crontab -e` and adding commands there. The commands work apart from the reboots. The reboots do not happen all the time. I wish to reboot at 4 am every morning. My added line is :

```
00 4 * * * root /sbin/shutdown -r now >> /var/log/daily-backup.log 2>&1
```

I now instead modified `/etc/crontab` instead for the reboots and it seems to work. Why is this? Shouldn't crontab -e work anyways because commands get run as root?

Answer (score 3):

If you do `crontab -e` then you're modifying the *per user* cron entry, typically in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USERNAME`.

Because these are per-user, they don't have the requirement for a username.

So the entry would look something like

```
00 4 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now >> /var/log/daily-backup.log 2>&1
```

In contrast, the `/etc/crontab` (and files in `/etc/cron.d/`) are sytem crontab entries, and so require a username.

You can see what `cron` is doing by looking at `/var/log/syslog` (on Debian; `/var/log/cron` on RedHat).  If your job is being called then there should be a line in your `daily-backup.log`... potentially saying that it can't find the "root" command.